# Addiction problem <PackageReference Include="Steeltoe.Connector.ConnectorCore" Version="3.1.0" />

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, steeltoe

In the project I am using dependencies

```xml
<PackageReference Include = "Steeltoe.Bootstrap.Autoconfig" Version = "3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include = "Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigServerBase" Version = "3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include = "Steeltoe.Messaging.RabbitMQ" Version = "3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include = "Steeltoe.Management.CloudFoundryCore" Version = "3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include = "Steeltoe.Discovery.Eureka" Version = "3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include = "Steeltoe.Management.EndpointCore" Version = "3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include = "Steeltoe.Common" Version = "3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include = "Steeltoe.Common.Hosting" Version = "3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include = "Steeltoe.Common.Http" Version = "3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include = "Steeltoe.Connector.CloudFoundry" Version = "3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include = "Steeltoe.Connector.EFCore" Version = "3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include = "Steeltoe.Discovery.ClientCore" Version = "3.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include = "Steeltoe.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigServerCore" Version = "3.1.0" />
```

But if you add a dependency:

```xml
<PackageReference Include = "Steeltoe.Connector.ConnectorCore" Version = "3.1.0" />
```

Then when the application starts, it gives an error:

> Cannot resolve scoped service 'RabbitMQ.Client.IConnectionFactory' from root provider.

The problem is solved by removing this dependency. If I understand correctly, then there is cross logic in this place. Perhaps you did not intend to share these packages. But the fact is on the face. Sharing is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This issue should be fixed in Steeltoe 3.1.1 by [this PR](https://github.com/SteeltoeOSS/Steeltoe/pull/744).

You can use the [Steeltoe CI feed](https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dotnet/Steeltoe/_packaging/dev/nuget/v3/index.json) to get pre-release packages now if you don't want to wait for 3.1.1 to hit nuget.org. Version 3.1.1-6303 and higher will include this fix.